# Bayesian Network: tools for simulation to create a sample set from reference Bayesian Networks?

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian-network

There are some commonly used reference Bayesian networks, which can be found in the [Bayesian Network Repository](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/%7Egalel/Repository/), and I want to simulate a data set from such a reference graph. Are there any tools that can help me do this? The tools need to be able to load the files of one of the formats in the Bayesian Network Repository (such as .bif and .dsc) and do the simulation to generate a number of samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AI Space Belief and Decision Networks tool may be of use to you. It opens XML files of the XMLBIF format. It also allows for editing a `.bif` representation of a network using an inbuilt text editor, so perhaps you can copy the `.bif` contents into the editor although I have not tested this myself. Here is a link to the webpage for the tool http://www.aispace.org/bayes/index.shtml, the website also has some other tools for networks which might be of use too.